# wget using --timeout and --tries together

Tags: linux, bash, wget

How long would you expect this command to take before exiting?

`wget --timeout=1 --tries=2 "http://www.google.com:81/not-there"`

I would expect a timeout of 1 seconds and 2 tries would mean 2 seconds, but it takes 6.025 seconds

```
wget --timeout=1 --tries=2 "http://www.google.com:81/not-there"
--2017-04-27 16:49:12--http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 209.85.203.105, 209.85.203.103, 209.85.203.99, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.105|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.103|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.99|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.104|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.106|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.147|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:4009:80d::2004|:81... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

I don't know why it tries 6 times before quitting.

It seems like `tries` is for retrying. If I set `--retry-connrefused` it at least does the retry, but still the total time taken isn't what I would expect. I'd like to be able to decide how many times it should try on a timeout.

**Edit**:

After a suggestion from @Socowi I tried using waitretry in combination with retry-connrefused and got the same behaviour:

```
$ wget --timeout=1 --waitretry=0 --tries=2 --retry-connrefused "http://www.google.com:81/not-there"
--2017-04-27 20:29:47--  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2a00:1450:400b:c00::68, 209.85.203.99, 209.85.203.147, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:400b:c00::68|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.99|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.147|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.103|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.104|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.106|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.105|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2017-04-27 20:29:54--  (try: 2)  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:400b:c00::68|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.99|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.147|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.103|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.104|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.106|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.105|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.
```

**Edit Two**

I was really confused when two identical commands behaved differently.

```
root@8c59d6dd05fe:/var/www/html# wget --timeout=1 --waitretry=0 --tries=2 --retry-connrefused "http://www.google.com:81/not-there"
converted 'http://www.google.com:81/not-there' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://www.google.com:81/not-there' (UTF-8)
--2017-04-27 19:50:28--  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 216.58.211.164, 2a00:1450:4009:805::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.211.164|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:4009:805::2004|:81... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Retrying.

--2017-04-27 19:50:29--  (try: 2)  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.211.164|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:4009:805::2004|:81... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Giving up.

root@8c59d6dd05fe:/var/www/html# wget --timeout=1 --waitretry=0 --tries=2 --retry-connrefused "http://www.google.com:81/not-there"
converted 'http://www.google.com:81/not-there' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://www.google.com:81/not-there' (UTF-8)
--2017-04-27 19:50:35--  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 209.85.203.104, 209.85.203.147, 209.85.203.106, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.104|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.147|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.106|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.103|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.105|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.99|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:400b:c03::68|:81... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Retrying.

--2017-04-27 19:50:41--  (try: 2)  http://www.google.com:81/not-there
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.104|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.147|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.106|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.103|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.105|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|209.85.203.99|:81... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:400b:c03::68|:81... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Giving up.
```

I thought I was going a bit crazy, but it was only when @Socowi pointed out in the comments that the IPs each retry were different that it clicked. It depends on the number of possible IPs being returned. The magic number 7 (retries) I was seeing was number the IP options. When I just choose one specific IP it only tries it once.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Wrong Number of Retries

Your wget seems to resolve the URL to multiple IP addresses as seen in the second line of your `wget`'s output. Each IP is then tested with the specified timeout. Unfortunately I haven't found any options to limit the DNS lookup to one address or set a total timeout for all IPs together. But you could try to use `"<googles ip address>:81/not-there"` instead of the domain name.

To automatically resolve the domain to a *single* IP address you can use

```
wget "http://$(getent hosts www.google.com | sed 's/ .*//;q'):81/not-there"
```

## Seemingly Too Long Timeout

As you already found out, setting `--retry-connrefused` lets `wget` retry even after a »*connection refused*« error. The specified timeout is used for each retry, but between the retries there will be a pause which gets longer after each retry.

#### Example

```
wget --timeout=1 --tries=5 --retry-connrefused URL
```

does something like

```
try to connect for 1 second
failed -> wait 1 second
try to connect for 1 second
failed -> wait 2 seconds
try to connect for 1 second
failed -> wait 3 second
try to connect for 1 second
failed -> wait 4 second
try to connect for 1 second
```

Therefore the command takes `tries * timeout + 1 + 2 + ... + (tries - 1)` seconds. This behavior is specified in `man wget` under the option, which allows you to change it :)

> **--waitretry=seconds**
> If you don't want Wget to wait between every retrieval, but only
> between retries of failed downloads, you can use this option.  Wget
> will use **linear backoff, waiting 1 second after the first failure
> on a given file, then waiting 2 seconds after the second failure on
> that file**, up to the maximum number of seconds you specify.
>
> By default, Wget will assume a value of 10 seconds.

I think you wanted to use something like

```
wget --timeout=1 --waitretry=0 --tries=5 --retry-connrefused URL
```

which eliminates the pause between two retries, resulting in a total time of `timeout * tries`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using the command you suggested still always tries to fetch it 7 times * tries. Why it always does it 7 times is beyond me. If you don't see the same problem I do then maybe it's something to do with versions? I'm on `GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on linux-gnu.`

Comment: I tried `GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu` and `GNU Wget 1.19.1 built on linux-gnu`, both with the result described in my answer.

Comment: I updated the description with the output from your suggestion

Comment: I don't know what's with me then, I tried on a docker container which had version 1.6 and got the same result. For timeout=1 and tries=2 it took 12 seconds.

Comment: Very strange. Sorry I couldn't help you. There's only one thing I have to add: Your `wget` seems to resolve the URL to multiple IP adresses (for me it is just one), as seen in the second line of your `wget`'s output. Each IP is then tested with the specified timeout. So the different behavior is probably caused by different DNS servers and not by `wget`. Unfortunately I haven't found any option to limit the DNS lookup to one address or set a total timeout for all IPs together. But you could try to use `"<googles ip address>:81/not-there"` instead of the URL to verify this theory.

Comment: I think you solved it :-D I was going really crazy because two consecutive identical commands produced different output! It's because of the DNS results. The mystical 7 retries was the number of possible IPs returned. If I pick just one then it works as expected. Very silly of me not to notice the difference in IP addresses it was trying every time. If you want to edit your last comment into your answer I'll accept it.